# What is please set your constraint for a plugin in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, constraints, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I am using this plugin called https://pub.dev/packages/android_alarm_manager .It says please set your constraint to android_alarm_manager: '>=0.4.y+x <2.0.0'

I dont understand what is the meaning of this y+x.I found a similar question but still I couldnt clearly figure out the meaning .My alarm manager plugin is not working properly on real devices though it works properly on the emulator or say in debug mode on my phone and I am thinking this has something to do with.

If you know as to any other reason as to why the alarm_manager plugin doesnt function properly on real devices please tell me and it will help me

Comment: How are you adding it in your pubspec? Try `android_alarm_manager: ^0.4.5+11`

Comment: @Sami Haddad I have used android_alarm_manager: ^0.4.5+9 .Will try and let you know.Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `android_alarm_manager: '>=0.4.y+x <2.0.0'` doesn't mean that you have to use `0.4.y+x`. Basically all it means that you need to use a version that starts with `0.4`. You can check the latest versions here:

https://pub.dev/packages/android_alarm_manager/versions

In your `pubspec.yaml`, add the following:

```
dependencies:
  android_alarm_manager: ^0.4.5+11
```

Comment: Ok thanks...@Peter Haddad....yeah but still Now I kind of get it that 5+11  stands for y+x,but what about the thing which says <2.0.0?

Comment: It just means less than 2.0.0

Comment: You just have to get the version from here https://pub.dev/packages/android_alarm_manager#-installing-tab-

Comment: I mean less than 2.0.0 is fine,but what should be less than 2.0.0?

Comment: The version number.. Of the plugin